# How to check whether the function execution complete in a current thread in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following code segment which does a filtering for the datagrid in C# WPF :

```
private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        VML.Layover.Busy = true; //shows a layover
        VML.SomeViewModel.TriggerdoSomething(); // doing an update in the UI and it will take some time 
        VML.Layover.Busy = false; // hides a laypover 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        VML.ErrorViewModel.ProjectLevelError = true;
    }
    VML.SystemFlyout.HideFlyout();
}
```

Um looking for a way to check whether the Triggersomething has completed
its a method which does filtering for the datagrid and I have to do it in the current thread.

How may I know if that process got completed ?

Comment: `and I have to do it in the current thread` if it runs on the current thread, it will block until it's done running. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to check if its completed in the current thread , cannot run in  other thread because the collection which um using for operations cannot be accessed

Comment: You should have tried `async` and `await` in such a situation

Comment: Are you sure that it has to be in the same thread? If not you could take a look at `AutoResetEvents`.

Comment: Yes it has to be in the same thread otherwise um getting an exception data set has been modified in a different thread like one